# Building error, cmake, can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: c++, build, cmake, shared, fpic

When I build a project with cmake, I got following error. Though I tried to add compiling flag `-fPIC` by `add_definition()` in the CMakeLists.txt, this error persists. Can anyone help? I am a new guy to [cmake](/questions/tagged/cmake). Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /act/mvapich2-1.9/gcc-4.7.2/lib/libmpich.a(mvapich_malloc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.bss' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/act/mvapich2-1.9/gcc-4.7.2/lib/libmpich.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/libstracker.so] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/xxxx/success/AutomaDeD-master'
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/stracker.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/xxxx/success/AutomaDeD-master'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

[add_definitions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_definitions.html) is is intended to add preprocessor definitions, not a flag

`-fPIC` is present by default in the linker flags for a shared library build with GCC, see [Modules/Compiler/GNU.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/Compiler/GNU.cmake). You can see all flags by running `make VERBOSE=1`.

As for the error itself, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6093910/2838364).