# When is it better for an assembler to use sign extended relocation like R_X86_64_32S instead of zero extension like R_X86_64_32?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64, elf, gnu-assembler

As a concrete example, on GAS 2.24, moving the address:

```
mov $s, %eax
s:
```

After:

```
as --64 -o a.o a.S
objdump -Sr a.o
```

Uses zero extension:

```
0000000000000000 <s-0x5>:
   0:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
                        1: R_X86_64_32  .text+0x5
```

But memory access:

```
mov s, %eax
s:
```

Compiles to sign extension:

```
0000000000000000 <s-0x7>:
   0:   8b 04 25 00 00 00 00    mov    0x0,%eax
                        3: R_X86_64_32S .text+0x7
```

Is there a rationale to using either in this specific case, or in general? I don't understand how the assembler could to any better supposition about either case.

NASM 2.10.09 just uses `R_X86_64_32` for both of the above. Update: an edge nasm commit 6377180 after 2.11 produces the same output of Gas, which seemed like a bug as Ross mentioned.

I have explained what I think I understand about `R_X86_64_32S` at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33289761/895245

Comment: Maybe it just can see that a value is small (especially zero!), but doesn't care to optimize address loads?

Comment: @BoPersson how can it know if addresses are going to be small (here it's 5) after linking? If I use a linker script with `. = 0xFFFFFFFF80000000;` like in this example http://stackoverflow.com/a/33289761/895245 it breaks for on `_32` but not `_32S`.

Answer (score 7):

The difference is in the allowed addresses for the symbol `s`. In the first case with R_X86_64_32, the symbol must be in the range of 0x00000000'00000000 to 0x00000000'FFFFFFFF. In the second case with R_X86_64_32S, the address of the symbol must between 0xFFFFFFFF'80000000 and 0x00000000'7FFFFFFF. If `s` ends up with an address outside of these ranges then linker will give an error.

This corresponds to how the CPU interprets the 32-bit value of `s` encoded into the two instructions. In the first instruction, where it's an immediate operand, the 32-bit value is zero extended into RAX. In the second instruction the 32-bit value is a displacement in a memory operand, and so is sign extended to form a 64-bit address.

NASM shouldn't be using the unsigned R_X86_64_32 relocation for the second instruction. It's not question of which one is better, using R_X86_64_32 here is simply incorrect. NASM would permit the address of `s` to be 0x00000000'80000000, but CPU would end up accessing 0xFFFFFFFF'80000000 instead.

Comment: Ah, nice, I had forgotten that `mov %eax` [zero extends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register)... and I had no idea that 32 bit addresses sign extended!

Answer (score 2):

With the immediate-data mov, the assembler is just doing what you wrote.  Writing to a 32bit register *always* zero-extends the upper32 in x86-64.  As documented in the Intel insn ref manual:

- `MOV r/m64, imm32` means: Move `imm32` sign extended to 64-bits to `r/m64`.
- `MOV r/m32, imm32` means: Move `imm32` to `r/m32`.

If you wanted sign-extension to match how 32bit addresses are treated in 32bit-absolute addressing modes, you should have written

```
mov $s, %rax
```

---

32bit displacements are always sign-extended.  So I think Ross's answer is right, that NASM 2.10.09 is buggy.  It's apparently telling the linker that the address will be zero-extended, when in fact it will be sign-extended.  Of course, RIP-relative addressing takes fewer instruction bytes, so it should be preferred over absolute addressing when possible.