# "relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.bss' can not be used when making a shared object”

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, linker-errors

I'm absolutely green in this but during classes, teacher gave us file he wrote just for us to run it and it worked fine then, but when I try to do it at home (I use Linux on VirtualBox) and use:

```
nasm -f elf64 hello.asm -o hello.o
gcc hello.o -o hello
```

I get an error "relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.bss' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC”. Can someone please explain what to do to make it work?

```
global main
extern printf

section .data
napis:      db ' Hello world! - po raz %ld',10,0

liczba_iteracji: equ 5

section .bss
licznik: resb 1

section .text

main:

push    rbp
mov rbp,rsp

mov byte [licznik],0

petla:              ;naiwna!

inc byte [licznik]

mov rdi, qword napis
mov rsi, qword [licznik]
mov rax, 0
call    printf

cmp byte [licznik],liczba_iteracji
jnz petla

mov rsp,rbp
pop rbp

mov rax,1           ;SYS_EXIT
mov rbx,0
int 80h
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do R\_X86\_64\_32S and R\_X86\_64\_64 relocation mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093547/what-do-r-x86-64-32s-and-r-x86-64-64-relocation-mean)

Comment: The answer about using  
    gcc -shared -fPIC foo.c -o libfoo.so doesnt solve my problem

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. The reason GCC gives this error is because it assumes (version 6.3.0 here) you are building a shared object (when, clearly, you are not), therefore presence of *.bss* makes it crazy. So you can either fix this by passing *-static* option: `gcc hello.o -static -o hello` (worked in my case), or using **Clang** as a linker: `clang hello.o -o hello`. No complaints from the latter.

Comment: PIE executable actually *are* ELF shared objects.  [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](//stackoverflow.com/q/43367427) The better fix is to avoid 32-bit absolute addressing where possible by using `default rel`, or by using `-fno-pie -no-pie` if there are cases where your code can be more efficient with absolute addressing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make certain you're writing [position independent code](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/03/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries/). The idea of PIC is that to make code truly position-independent, you need at least one level of indirection. That level of indirection is IP-relative addressing, and when that is not enough, you will need a second layer, the Global Offset Table or GOT.

In NASM, you will find the [DEFAULT REL](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.02/html/nasmdoc6.html#section-6.2.1) directive(s) useful.

Comment: PIE executables don't need to indirect through the GOT for access to their own functions / vars; that's only to support symbol interposition.  `gcc -fPIC` implies shared-library symbol interposition, but the modern default of `gcc -fpie -pie` only needs to avoid 32-bit absolute addressing.  So yes, `default rel`.   [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](//stackoverflow.com/q/43367427)